# How does backpropagation work for Variational AutoEncoder?

Tags: deep-learning, backpropagation

I understand that by reparameterization, Gaussian noise(0,I) is taken as input whereas, thereby making the entire network differentiable.

I am not able to understand how this is implemented. As such, how are the dimensions of gradient mapped.

Answer (score 0):

The backpropagation for VAE's happen via the "Reparametrization trick". You should get more information in the answers to the stakexhange question here : https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/199605/68370